# Animated Plot: Tick Labels Disrupt Smooth PlotRange Expansion

Tags: plotting, animation, ticks

I am making animations for educational purposes that compare projectile trajectories in different environments. Each animation starts with a reference trajectory. Then, at least one projectile is superimposed and released.

In most cases, these projectiles travel a lot higher and a lot farther than the reference trajectory, but I don't want to give that away at the beginning. So, each animation starts with a plot range that nicely encompasses reference trajectory. Then, as the featured projectile moves, the plot range expands to keep it in view.

I want this expansion to be smooth. However, whenever a new tick label appears, the plot range jumps forward to accommodate said label. The expansion then freezes until the projectile reaches the end of the new plot range, at which point the expansion continues smoothly until a new tick label appears and the process repeats. The result is an animation that is not smooth and not to my liking.

Here is a simplified example I've been playing around with:

```
referenceFunction = {132.09935961236326` t, 
  3.2808398950131235` + 70.8667452497465` t - 16.076115485564305` t^2}

referenceBounds = t /. Solve[0 == Last@referenceFunction]
PrependTo[referenceBounds, t]

referenceTrajectory = 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@referenceFunction, Evaluate@referenceBounds, 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}]

exampleFunction[t_] = {132.09935961236326` t, 
  3.2808398950131235` + 70.8667452497465` t - 2.662724845231996` t^2}

{tStart, tStop} = t /. Solve[0 == Last@exampleFunction[t]]

exampleTrajectory[time_] := 
 ParametricPlot[exampleFunction[t], {t, tStart, time}]

showOptions = {ImageSize -> Large, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Horizontal Label", "Vertical Label"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Larger}, PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}};

animateThis[time_] := 
 Show[{referenceTrajectory, exampleTrajectory[time]}, showOptions]

Animate[animateThis[time], {time, 0, tStop}, DefaultDuration -> tStop,
  DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

I am using `Frame` and `FrameTicks` instead of `Axes` and `Ticks` because I prefer the centered and rotated positions of `FrameLabel`. The same problem occurs with `Axes` and `Ticks`.

I have tried several potential fixes, including but not limited to writing custom `PlotRange` functions, trying different `PlotRangePadding` and `FrameTicksStyle` options, turning `GridLines` off, etc. So far, nothing aside from removing the frame tick labels altogether has worked, and I prefer having those labels! I just don't want them to affect `PlotRange` when they render.

So, I am deferring to the experts; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Adding `ImagePadding -> 60` to your `showOptions` seems to work.

Comment: I hadn't considered using any `Image` options, but `ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}` gives me exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! If you'd like some extra reputation, write this solution as an answer and I'll give it the accept.